# Count the number of cells between each occurrence of found number

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I am trying to go down a column of numbers and count the number of cells between each occurrence.

But first it goes to a cell to get the number to be searched.

I have the first part. It will find the number to be searched.
It then does the search.

When it returns the array, the count is inaccurate.
It shows random numbers.

```
 If Z = 5 Then ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select: Z = 0: x = x + 1
  Select Case Selection.Value
   Case Is = 1000
   GoSub passarrayp
   Case Is = 100
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select: x = x + 1: Z = 0 'Exit Do
   Case Is = searchp
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select: p = p + 1: DataArray1(p) = x: x = 1: Z = 0
   Case Is = 50
   Range("h:h").Select: Selection.ClearContents: Range("a3").Select: GoSub final
   Case Is <> searchp
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select: Z = Z + 1
 End Select
  Loop
  Next Z

  GoSub passarrayp
 'Transfer the array to the worksheet
 passarrayp:
 'finds an empty cell to put the number of undrawn weeks
 Range("k46").Select
 Do While ActiveCell <> searchp
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
 Loop
 Do
 If ActiveCell = searchp Then ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select: c = p: _
'places array values onto spreadsheet
 Selection.Resize(1, c + 1).Value = DataArray1: Exit Do
Loop
        'Zero array elements ready for next search
r = 0 ' starts the array reset from from the first element
For i = 0 To 249
r = r + 1: DataArray1(p) = 0 ' clear the  array element values to zero
Next i ' increments the elements to be zeroed
```

Comment: Make it easy for us to help you. Please show an example of your data, expected output, actual output.

Comment: Thanks for replying Ron
These are data.
I was expecting to see
for the number 10, for example, I would expect to see
6, 11, and 4,

These numbers are the count between the numbers.
Or to put it another way (in case I've not explained myself well), 
the number of weeks between the number 10 being drawn from a lottery
12
3
5
4
11
10
11
2
9
11
13
11
14
13
13
5
10
5
2
11
10
9
1


Hope this clarifies it
kindest regards
Owen

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently.

**Edit:** *edit code and screenshot to make first item consistent*

Collect the relevant row numbers in a Collection, and then output an array with the difference between the relevant row numbers:

```
Option Explicit
Function countBetween(Draws As Range, LookFor As Long) As Long()
    Dim colRowNums As Collection
    Dim C As Range
    Dim rowDiffs() As Long
    Dim firstRow As Long
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim lTemp() As Long, I As Long

'find first row with data in Draws Range
'  we do this just in case user picked the non-numeric header row
' could do more extensive checking

If IsNumeric(Draws(1, 1)) Then
    firstRow = Draws(1, 1).Row
Else
    firstRow = Draws(2, 1).Row
End If

'collect each row number of interest
'could also loop, but `.Find` should be faster on long arrays

Set colRowNums = New Collection
With Draws
    Set C = .Find(what:=LookFor, after:=Draws(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = C.Address
        colRowNums.Add C.Row

        Do
            Set C = .Find(what:=LookFor, after:=C)
            If Not C.Address = firstAddress Then
                colRowNums.Add C.Row
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End With

'If first entry in Draws was LookFor, then it will be last in the list
' So check for that and exchange if necessary

If colRowNums(1) > colRowNums(colRowNums.Count) Then
    colRowNums.Add Item:=colRowNums(colRowNums.Count), before:=1
    colRowNums.Remove (colRowNums.Count)
End If

'create output array
ReDim lTemp(1 To colRowNums.Count, 1 To 1) 'for vertical outputl
lTemp(1, 1) = colRowNums(1) - firstRow + 1
For I = 2 To colRowNums.Count
    lTemp(I, 1) = colRowNums(I) - colRowNums(I - 1)
Next I

countBetween = lTemp
End Function
```

The function will return a vertical array of values.
If you have O365 with dynamic arrays, you can just enter:

```
=countBetween(Draws,LookFor)
```

in a single cell and the results will Spill down.

If you don't you could either enter the formula as an array-formula over a range of cells, or use the `INDEX` function as:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(countBetween(Draws,LookFor),ROWS($1:1)),"")
```

and fill down until you see blanks.

[image]

**EDIT** *for horizontal array output:*

If you want a horizontal output of the results, as I wrote in the comments, since you now have O365, all you need to do is use the `TRANSPOSE` function.  eg:

```
=TRANSPOSE(countBetween(A2:A23,B2))
```

Or, you could change the method you use to create the output array:

```
'for horizontal output
ReDim lTemp(1 To colRowNums.Count)
lTemp(1) = colRowNums(1) - firstRow + 1
For I = 2 To colRowNums.Count
    lTemp(I) = colRowNums(I) - colRowNums(I - 1)
Next I
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help ROn.
Forgive my stupidity, as I'm learning on the fly, so to speak.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help Ron.
Forgive my stupidity, as I'm learning on the fly, so to speak.

The data are vertical, as you mentioned, so your suggestion would be fine.

However, I have tried to insert your code, as well as run it on it's own, as I wasn't sure if its a program in it's own right.
Either way it doesn't work, I'm afraid.
when I run it, it expects a sub routine Sub, end sub. Which prevents it from running.
Thanks again for your help

Also, your other 2 suggestions? Are they just a formula on the spread sheet?
Kindest regards
Owen

Comment: I don't understand what you have written. Why do you think it is calling a Sub?  What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What do you mean by "program"? The code is a User Defined Function.written in VBA.  If it didn't work, how would I have created the screen shot?  What do you mane by "other 2 suggestions"? I only provided one instance of a UDF.

Comment: It's almost 2.30.
My brain hurts.
Remember those old disaster movies when the guy in the flight tower has to talk the never flown a plane before passenger how to land the plane?
I'm the passenger at the controls of the plane......
good night sir lol

Comment: By the way.
i have used the snipping tool to get a screen shot, but I don't know how to upload it..

Comment: @OwenFalconer No annoyance. Just trying to clarify your question so I can understand it. My old brain sometimes needs things laid out specifically before that can happen.  And yes, the UDF I wrote stands alone. You copy/paste it into a "regular module" and then use the `=countBetween(…` function on your worksheet. `Draws` and `LookFor` are named ranges that refer to (what seems to me to be) the obvious on the worksheet in columns A and B

Comment: Thanks for your patience Ron (they do Ron,Ron, Ron. They do Ron Ron)
Sorry, the that song got stuck in my head when I first saw your name. And it's stuck ever since lo

Anyhow, pray tell, how you you post a screen shot?
So you can see what happening, when I attempt to run it.

In the mean time. 
The only way to describe the issue, is that when I click on the Run icon, within the development screen (where you can see the code), I get an error message "Ambiguous name detected: Countbetween

I clicked on Insert (Module)Pasted your code

Comment: "Ambiguous name detected: Countbetween I clicked on Insert (Module)Pasted your code
Pasted your codeinto the blank module

I then copied and pasted =countBetween(F4:F106,1). onto the worksheet.
It's a this point that I get the error message on the module screen
Thanks again.

I am confident that the plane will land safely with your guidance lol

Comment: =countBetween(Draws,LookFor) I originally pasted it onto the worksheep verbatim, like above.
But that too had the same Ambiguous error

Comment: I've solved the ambiguous name problem Ron.
I have two copies of the same module with your code....oops lol
However, I cam only getting one number on the worksheet.
Unlike your screen shot, where is cascades down

Comment: @OwenFalconer Which worksheet formula are you using?  If you don't ***have O365 with dynamic arrays***, you will have to either enter that formula as an array over several cells, or, (and preferably in my opinion), use the second formula and fill down at least until you see blanks.

Comment: Morning Ron. I have managed to turn the plane around and heading for the airport, so to speak. hehehe. I have installed O365 and checked that dynamic arrays is on. I tried both formulas. The Countbetween one came up with  name error at first. But when I retyped it, Excel gave me the option to choose the macro. So this is what it looks like =VBAProject.Module5.countBetween(Draws,LookFor). But I just get # hash's in the cell where I have pasted the formula

Comment: RON! RON! RON! the plane is almost landing hahahaha. I have got the same result as you...whoop whoop.. is there a way to automate transpoing the result so it is across rows, rather than down colums? thats it then. I won't bug you anymore after that hahahahaha

Comment: @OwenFalconer Did you try the `TRANSPOSE` function?  Or, in the code, you can change the output array from 2D to 1D. With regard to that, suggest you read the late Chip Pearson's article on [VBA Arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: Thanks  Ron.
I read the article and got a better understanding of arrays.
I then tried to copy and paste it into your coding, and fell flat on my face lol.
The interesting (and frustrating lol) thing is, Excel won't let me manually transpose the result either

Comment: @OwenFalconer How did you try to use the `TRANSPOSE` function?

Comment: I couldn't literally copy the column of result, and the paste special.
However. I have found that I have to copy and paste the value first.
then copy again and transpose

Comment: @OwenFalconer That is not using the `TRANSPOSE` **Function**.  Look up the **function** using HELP

Comment: @OwenFalconer Also, see the latest Edit to my answer.